# Explanation of the arm cortex a/r/m numbering convention

Tags: arm

I've been looking around some web sources, but I can not find the meaning of the numbers after the processor type of the ARM family. For example Cortex-A53, I know it refers to the application family, hence the A, the 5 might refer that it contains MMU(not sure though), but the 3 I have no idea...can you please provide an explanation or sources?

Comment: Looking at the ["List of ARM microarchitecture"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ARM_microarchitectures) article on Wikipedia (a very handy table they've got there, BTW), I do not think it's as simple as you assume. I don't think each digit has a particular, well-defined meaning...  I wonder if someone knows better.

Comment: You are overthinking this it is clearly not some bit or digit encoding, its just numbers.  Quite often marketing simply picks things out of the air, next one bigger than the former.  maybe they have a pair of magic dice and they keep rolling them until they get a number they like.  Its just numbers I wouldnt get too worked up about it, they are unique so we can tell products apart.

Comment: You would have to get a job at arm and hang out with the marketing department if you want sources.  And again you might not like what you find.  Number of shots of whiskey before the bosses pet passed out, the new hire passed out.  the team passed out.  Number of pencils in the ceiling thrown David Letterman style in the marketing conference room...and I am not joking this is sometimes how these things are done.

Comment: usually the formula is the new one has to have a bigger number than the last one

Comment: Well,  I decided that I will not overthinking too much. I just thought so, because the architectures and/or processors that are not from the Cortex-X family, DO have a menaning. just thought so...

Comment: I believe that all Cortex-A will have an MMU (but it doesn't have to be enabled).  The Cortex-M and Cortex-R may come with a PMU (physical address properties) but they may have nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the Cortex-A processors there are three major sub-groups which are worth knowing about:

Cortex-A3x => smaller cores, mostly designed for embedded systems and low-cost mobile.

Cortex-A5x => "LITTLE" cores in the Arm big.LITTLE / DynamIQ heterogeneous compute architecture (so lower peak performance than the "big" cores, but better energy efficiency).

Cortex-A7x => "big" cores in the Arm big.LITTLE / DynamIQ heterogeneous compute architecture (so higher peak performance than the "LITTLE" cores, but lower energy efficiency).

Within each those groups the bigger value of "x" will be the newer CPU cores, which nearly always have both improved energy efficiency and peak performance than the lower numbered ones within that group.

The specific numbers don't have specific decode for "has an MMU" or anything like that (unless you go back a long time - some of the early ARM7 and ARM9 CPU names did).

For Cortex-M and R, they don't really have the same tiers - in general bigger number = bigger and faster core with more recent ISA extensions to add new capabilities.

The only significant banding that exists is the Cortex-R5x series (which is ARMv8-R architecture including 64-bit support, where as the single digit R cores are all 32-bit Armv7 cores).

Comment: Thanks!...very useful... could you either explain as well for the cortex R family, or provide sources?

Comment: Answer updated to add R and M, but on the whole it's less useful information, sorry.